# How to parse json string to different columns in spark scala?

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

While reading parquet file this is the following file data

```
|id |name |activegroup|

|1  |abc  |[{"groupID":"5d","role":"admin","status":"A"},{"groupID":"58","role":"admin","status":"A"}]|
```

data types of each field

root

```
|--id : int
|--name : String
|--activegroup : String
```

activegroup column is string explode function is not working. Following is the required output

```
|id |name |groupID|role|status|
|1  |abc  |5d     |admin|A    |
|1  |def  |58     |admin|A    |
```

Do help me with parsing the above in spark scala latest version

Comment: How to solve it for spark 2.3 version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to extract the json schema:

```scala
  val schema = schema_of_json(lit(df.select($"activeGroup").as[String].first))
```

Once you got it, you can convert your activegroup column, which is a String to json (`from_json`), and then `explode` it.

Once the column is a json, you can extract it's values with `$"columnName.field"`

```
  val dfresult = df.withColumn("jsonColumn", explode(
                                      from_json($"activegroup", schema)))
                   .select($"id", $"name",
                           $"jsonColumn.groupId" as "groupId", 
                           $"jsonColumn.role" as "role", 
                           $"jsonColumn.status" as "status")
```

If you want to extract the whole json and the element names are ok to you you can use the * to do it:

```
val dfresult = df.withColumn("jsonColumn", explode(
                               from_json($"activegroup", schema)))
            .select($"id", $"name", $"jsonColumn.*")
```

**RESULT**

```
+---+----+-------+-----+------+
| id|name|groupId| role|status|
+---+----+-------+-----+------+
|  1| abc|     5d|admin|     A|
|  1| abc|     58|admin|     A|
+---+----+-------+-----+------+
```

Comment: This is not working with spark.sql 2.3 version. 
Can someone help me to solve from this version @SCouto

Comment: it should work, I answer this with spark 2.4 i think, which is your error?